# overwrite parent method partially in python

Tags: python, inheritance, overwrite

I have a situation when I need to overwrite parent method but only in one line. My initial code is quite big so I clarify what I mean in an example.
I have method from parent:

```
class parent():
    def method(self):
        bla
        bla
        print("Parent method is working")
        bla
        bla
```

And child:

```
class child(parent):
    def method(self):
        bla
        bla
        print("Child method working")
        bla
        bla
```

As you can see, two methods are pretty much the same but one line is different. Do I have to write the same code in child method just to print different output or there is dark magic in python how to overwrite only one line?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can introduce an helper method that you override in the child.

```
class parent(object):
  def method(self):
    blah
    self.helper()
    blah
  def helper(self):
    print("parent running")

class child(parent):
  def helper(self):
    print("child running")
```

Answer (score 4):

There isn't a magic way to do so, you have to rewrite the entire method.

Now, of course, there are various workarounds. If you can edit the parent, then you can:

1. Separate out the part you want to override in the child in a separate method to be re-implemented in the child.
2. If feasible, pass an argument (or even use a class attribute) to the method to alter the method's behavior.

In your case, method #1 would look like:

```
class Parent(object):
     def method(self):
         print("Before!")
         self.inner()
         print("After!")

     def inner(self):
         print "In the parent"
```

And the child:

```
class Child(Parent):
    def inner(self):
        print("In the child")
```